# Permission denied after successful build

Tags: read-the-docs

I am trying to import my first project into Read the Docs (readthedocs.io). After much fidgeting with the git hooks, I am now able to import and successfully build my mkdocs repo.

But as soon as I click on "View Docs", I have the following error on the page:

> Permission Denied
>   You don't have the proper permissions to view this page. Please contact     the owner of this project to request permission.

I cannot find any reason why that could happen (i'm logged in with my owner credentials).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried setting the "latest version" to *public* instead of *private*, and now I can view my doc. I don't know why I couldn't view it as the owner of the project before... Nevermind. Hope that helps.

Best,
Kristina